# tikz: azeotropic graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

Do you know an example, even a minimal one, in order to draw the graph of an azeotropic mixture with tikz?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have the data? This looks like a job for `pgfplot`.

Comment: I only need some generic curves, no precise data are needed

Comment: You should be able to just use pgfplot and plot a couple of polynomial approximations, fitting the polynomial is off topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a just-do-it-for-me question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is to give you a start.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,3) -- (0,0) node[below] {$0$} -- (3,0) node[midway,below] {$\chi_A$}
 node[below] {$1$} -- (3,3);
 \draw[blue,thick] (0,2) coordinate(L1) node[black,left] {$T_B$} 
 to[out=-60,in=-135] coordinate[pos=0.65] (p1) 
  (3,1) coordinate(R1) node[black,right] {$T_A$} ;
 \draw[red,thick,looseness=0.8] (L1) to[out=10,in=170] (p1) node[below,black] {$T_\mathrm{min}$}
  to[out=-10,in=160] (R1);
 \path[font=\sffamily] (1,0.5) node {liquido} (2,2.5) node {vapore};
 %
 \begin{scope}[xshift=4.5cm]
  \draw (0,3) -- (0,0) node[below] {$0$} -- (3,0) node[midway,below] {$\chi_A$}
  node[below] {$1$} -- (3,3);
  \draw[blue,thick] (0,2) coordinate(L2) node[black,left] {$T_B$} 
  to[out=-20,in=180,looseness=2] ++ (1,0.3) coordinate (p2) to[out=00,in=135]
   ++(1,-1.25)  to[out=-45,in=160]
   (3,1) coordinate(R2) node[black,right] {$T_A$} ;
  \draw[red,thick,looseness=0.8] (L2) to[out=30,in=180] (p2) 
  node[above,black] {$T_\mathrm{max}$}
   to[out=0,in=130] (R2);
  \path[font=\sffamily] (1,0.5) node {liquido} (2,2.5) node {vapore};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]